# How would you cover this vent?

Tags: vent, air

I'm moving into a new home and one of biggest pet peeves I have is this vent in the living room. Any ideas for how to cover it?

Do they have invisible frames that I could use instead?

Any ideas/thoughts would be appreciated!

Correction: I believe this is just where you change the filter. I'm not sure if it needs adequate air supply or not. Regardless I need to able to access it every few months for filter changes. I can't close it off because I'll need to change filters every few months. I'm not a fan of "covering it with a book case" because thats where I want to media unit to go (and its not as high)

[image: b]
[image: a]

Comment: Are there other vents whose appearance you like more? Or are you asking about for to completely cover it up (eliminating the airflow)?

Comment: That's a beautiful plant. Why are we looking at it?

Comment: Blocking vents is a really bad idea, it can lead to multiple other problems. You might REPLACE it with something more aesthetically pleasing (o maybe less displeasing) such as a decorative grate. Or...just quit looking at it. Humans tend to notice things like that only at first. Eventually we become "habituated" to our surroundings, meaning we stop seeing details the same way.

Comment: @JACK it’s the vent (probably a return vent) to right of the plant...it’s located directly below the supply vent.

Comment: @LeeSam  I was being sarcastic and wondering why they didn't move the table and give us a good picture of the vent in question. :-)  Stay safe out there.

Comment: looks like there is an `invisible frame` already ... lol

Comment: @LeeSam wow! I didn't even notice that return vent! All I saw was the supply vent up by the ceiling.

Comment: @FreeMan, that looks like an in-wall heater

Comment: @FreeMan Correction: This is just where you change the filter. I don't believe it's a vent.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion (this is not suppose to be an opinion site) you need to disguise the vents. One way would be to add a large bookcase along the entire wall. This would give you an opportunity to cover the barn door hardware too.

Don’t “cover” the vents. Let them be exposed behind pictures of your cat, knickknacks from your last trip to Greece, books, etc.

I’d move the thermostat out to be flush with the face of the books, but I’d leave the outlet and switch recessed.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question. I believe this is just where you change the filter. I'm not sure if it needs adequate air supply or not. Regardless I need to able to access it every few months for filter changes.

Comment: They make bookcases that open up to secret rooms, this one could certainly swing to access any filters, etc.  You could install the media unit in a portion of the cabinetry.

Comment: The difference between having a media center in the room and a bookcase with a media center is aesthetically it’s like having an item in the room and having an element of the room.

Answer (score -2):

Two ways to approach this.  If you have the money, you can just have the vent moved to a different location.  Just hire a competent HVAC contractor or a HVAC engineer to tell you where you should have it placed.

The second option is to make the seller move it.  This will take bit of effort and time.  You have to first determine whether that's a supply or return.

Do not rely on a home inspector to tell you.  They are a complete waste of money and they really should be illegalized.  Nearly all of them have no construction experience and simply take a course to get licensed.  You think that a simple course will teach them all the ins and outs of proper construction?  An experienced GC whose worked for years will have a hard time knowing everything.

You should turn on the cooling and heating to see if the air is conditioned evenly throughout the entire house, especially with housing units that have multiple levels connected or cathedral ceilings.  Think of air as water with hot water slowly moving to the top and cold water moving to the bottom.

With respect to that specific vent, it looks like a return vent meaning the air is moving hot air back to the air conditioner.  Supply vents usually have some manual trigger to control the air flow although that is not always the case.  To check to see if it's a return, turn on the system and place a piece of paper over it.  See if the paper is blowing away from the vent or it sticks to it.  If it sticks to it, then it's a return.  It shouldn't be next to a window.  That's where the supply is.

At this point, you can ask the seller to move it to the middle of the room where it's supposed to be, after getting an HVAC contractor or hiring an HVAC engineer to verify everything I'm saying and stating that it's improper to have the HVAC located there.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! This is the second answer of yours I've read in the last hour or so, and they both contain rants against something/someone. While you may be absolutely correct, they add nothing whatsoever to your answer and really aren't appropriate. If you'll pull the couple of paragraphs with the rants out, you'll have some great answers. With them, they read as little more than rants, really don't meet the standards expected for answers around here, and are likely to get flagged for deletion (though I haven't flagged either. Yet.)

Comment: Yeah, agreed this is not the place to rant about home inspectors, especially since OP never mentioned inspections.

Comment: FreeMan, you're right and stupid on my part.  It's maddening that for almost every question on StackExchange, there are inexperienced people that are answering the question incorrectly.  What is further making me crazy is that those responses seem correct to the average user so they get a lot of upvotes.  I mean what the hell.